# Create language version of all items under path

Tags: powershell, sitecore, version, sitecore8.2

I have a ton of items that I need to create a French language version for, and I'd like to use SPE to do this rather than going through manually adding a language version for hundreds of items. I'm running this command in PowerShell console:

```
Get-ChildItem /sitecore/content/Global/Components/Web Forms/Country -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq "CountryLookup" } | 
    ForEach-Object { Add-ItemLanguage $_ -Language "en" -TargetLanguage "fr" -IfExist Skip}
```

When I run it, it doesn't return any errors or give me any output, and when I check the items under /sitecore/content/Global/Components/Web Forms/Country there are still no French versions. What's wrong with my PowerShell command?

Comment: First I would try to narrow it down. Are you sure your loop has items in its pipeline? You can try adding { 'test'; Add-Item .... } and see if it returns anything. If not, there's an issue with the where clause.

Comment: I tested your script and it works well for me. Are you sure your template name is correct? If you run first 2 line of your script, does it return any items?

Comment: It appears the issue is the path:
Cannot find path 'master:\sitecore\content\Global\Components\Web' because it does not exist

How do you include spaces in the path?

Comment: figured it out- wrapping the path in quotes fixed the space issue

Comment: Given that your problem was simply neglecting to quote a path with embedded spaces, can I suggest you delete your question? It is unlikely to benefit future readers. On a side note, it sounds like `$ErrorActionPreference` was set to `SilentlyContinue` or `Ignore`, otherwise `Get-ChildItem` would have complained.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this by using Add-ItemVersion and "fr-FR" as target language.

```
Add-ItemVersion  $_ -Language "en" -TargetLanguage "fr-FR" -IfExist Skip
```